# Kendo UI MVC Grid - Inline Editing - Update All Columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid (MVC) that has multiple Columns.

I have a use case where if Column 1 is edited, the value of Column 2 *may* change server-side.  I'm not seeing the modified values in the grid though.

My Update API handles all of this and returns the updated row.
But with inline editing, it seems that if I update Column 1, the other columns aren't refreshing after the Update is finished.  So I (the user) has to manually refresh the Grid in order to see Column 2 correctly modified.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Kendo dataSource requestEnd to refresh your grid.

Add `requestEnd: onRequestEnd,` to your dataSource

and add the function

```
function onRequestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type == "create" || e.type == "update" || e.type == "delete") {
        e.sender.read();
    }
}
```